# Android Studio Project with path *** could not be found in root project

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to compile the android desk clock and alarm clock from here:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock/+/marshmallow-release

I downloaded the tgz and extracted it, and opened in Android Studio. When I try to build it, I got an error about not having android-opt-datetimepicker in the root of the project. So I grabbed that from 
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/datetimepicker/+/marshmallow-release

And I put it in a subdirectory under my root. I still can't compile it.

[image: Android Studio Screenshot]

[image: Folder Structure]

Comment: Since I last posted this, I have tried placing the datetimepicker project in a few other places ("alongside" the deskclock project, and inside the src folder). Neither worked. I also tried a few edits of the build.gradle file. Namely, I did see a tutorial that indicated that the "dependencies" section should not be inside the "android" section. Since I hadn't made any changes to in since I downloaded it, I didn't think any changes would be necessary, but I tried it anyway. Again, no joy.

Comment: Could you find a solution to this problem? If yes, can you please post your solution..